# incomplete list of csv file imported in R

Tags: r, csv, import

I need to import a list of 36 csv files, but after running the code I get only 26 of them. Probably, 10 files have format problems. Is there a way in R to detect the 10 files that cannot be imported?

Comment: Print the name of the file read by R in the console, maybe?

Comment: The imported files become a data frame, so if I print the name of the dataframe I get the observations and variables, not the name of the files.

Comment: That is why I suggest to print the name of the **file**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you the file names in a list, you can use the following code:

```
all <- c("16048.txt", "16062.txt", "16066.txt", "16093.txt", "16095.txt", "16122.txt", "16241.txt", "16360.txt", "16380.txt", "16389.txt", "16510.txt", "16511.txt", "16701.txt", "16729.txt", "16735.txt", "16737.txt", "16761.txt", "16816.txt", "16867.txt", "16876.txt", "16880.txt", "16883.txt", "16884.txt", "16885.txt", "16893.txt", "16904.txt", "16906.txt", "16908.txt", "16929.txt", "16931.txt", "16938.txt", "16943.txt", "16959.txt", "16967.txt", "16968.txt", "16969.txt")
imp <- c("16761.txt", "16959.txt", "16884.txt", "16093.txt", "16883.txt", "16122.txt", "16906.txt", "16737.txt", "16968.txt", "16095.txt", "16062.txt", "16816.txt", "16360.txt", "16893.txt", "16885.txt", "16938.txt", "16048.txt", "16931.txt", "16876.txt", "16511.txt", "16969.txt", "16241.txt", "16967.txt", "16701.txt", "16380.txt", "16510.txt")
```

Where `all` is the list of filenames you need and `imp` is the imperfect result you got. You can get a list of the missing files with:

```
missing <- all[!all %in% imp]
```

Comment: Thank you Jaap! That´s useful!